# Unused files in Apache Struts project

Tags: java, apache, jsp, servlets, struts

I have recently inherited a project at work written using Apache Struts and its a bit of a mess, with quite a few unused files like jsp, java, css.

Is there an easy way of identifying unused files without having to manually check? It is a very large application so I really hope that won't be necessary!

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way of doing this with 100% accuracy, especially when it comes to JSPs, CSS, etc. You can try to do some code coverage analysis, but this is not a guarantee either. If it is a large and complex application, I'd be rather careful. Remove those artifacts definitely not used any more. Btw, this is a great way of understanding the 'mess' you just inherited :-)

Answer (score 1):

despite what people love to tell you, yes this can be done - I asked this question recently - there are 2 ways firstly you can do this and it shows an alarming misunderstanding of the nature of statistics in maths in SO.

Basically you can aim to create an incredibly large "probability" that a file is unused, and it's a great victory of "theory" over "common sense" when people would argue you should not do this.

in my example there were about ten years of live data to work from. It would be important to get the highest lowest incidence of frequency of a positive result on a file in your project before you could rule out whether the file is a dead file never served up. The higher the lowest used file count the better.

The two ways:

- use an apache log analyser like this tool http://www.apacheviewer.com/features.php (pay to use) I actually didn't go for this approach so your mileage may vary and it does depend on your logging but this theoretically is a sound approach
- @Michael Hampton's trick of getting the last accessed datetime from the OS

OP

https://serverfault.com/questions/513587/apache-log-can-they-be-used-to-see-if-a-file-is-ever-called-used/513618#513618